# Find UIView by memory address in XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

I am currently receiving the following error:

```
Failed to set (borderIBColor) user defined inspected property on 
(UIView): [<UIView 0x7f8dda6075b0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this 
class is not key value coding-compliant for the key borderIBColor.
```

I need to change the user-defined property but I have no idea *which* `UIView` the compiler is referring to!

Is there any way to take this information and find the `UIView` so I can fix it? I have been going through every view in the `storyboard` trying to find it, but it's taking forever.

Comment: Open Storyboard/Xib as XML and look for "borderIBColor". You should find one. Else, you should be able put a breakpoint on it, and by doing `po [((UIView *) 0x7f8dda6075b0) frame]` you could get its frame, or be able to get other infos. You could also do `po [((UIView *) 0x7f8dda6075b0) setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]` to spot it (if obv you don't change color in code elsewhere overriding the command, or another color if you already use redColor)

Comment: Thank you, opening storyboard as Source Code and doing ctrl+F fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Larme's comment, opening storyboard as Source Code and doing ctrl+F fixed my problem.